# how to use order by random in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, random, sql-order-by

While Searching I want to show the paid customers firstly, and then rest of customers list

but the problem is I want to show by random
for Example. paid customers should not mix with others.
Can anyone tell what will be query?

please help me!
I am using codeigniter

Comment: Have you designed the tables? Can you show it to us?

Comment: Hey Raman, it would be great if you could show us what you've tried first, then we could try to help you with your query. Sounds like you might want to use a join.

Comment: i have tried this sql  SELECT * FROM (`dbc_posts`) WHERE `featured` = '1' AND `status` = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0

Comment: Here Featured = 1 means PAID

Comment: try SELECT * FROM `dbc_posts` where `featured` = 1 AND `status` = 1 ORDER BY rand()

Comment: What's your code so far?

Comment: but i want to show both featured & rest of customer in result i want to show firstly featured but they should show randomly & then rest of customers but randomly. i don't want to mix them.

Comment: $this->db->order_by('id', 'random'); 
$this->db->order_by('featured', 'desc'); 
$query = $this->db->get('posts',$limit,$start);

Comment: @RamanSaluja check my answer see if it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql query for your need if i understood well

```
SELECT `featured`,group_concat(`id` order by rand() ) as `id` FROM `dbc_posts` where `status` = 1 GROUP By `featured` ORDER BY `featured` DESC
```

now with php

```
 $results  =  $this->db->query("SELECT `featured`,group_concat(`id` order by rand() ) as `id` FROM `dbc_posts` where `status` = 1 GROUP By `featured`  ORDER BY `featured` DESC")->result_array(); 

    $paid = $results[0];//featured = 1

    // comma seprated ids of the paid people e.g :- 3,7,1,26,92  are available in 
    $paidusers = $results[0]["id"];
    //seprate them by 
    $paidusers = explode(",",$paidusers);

    foreach($paidusers as $paiduser)
    {
        $row  =  $this->db->get_where("dbc_posts", array("id"=> $paiduser))->row();
        print_r($row );
        echo "<br>";
    }
     // do same for unpaid 
        $unpaid = $results[1];//featured = 0
    $unpaidusers = $results[1]["id"];
    //seprate them by 
    $unpaidusers = explode(",",$unpaidusers);

    foreach($unpaidusers as $unpaiduser)
    {
        $row  =  $this->db->get_where("dbc_posts", array("id"=> $unpaiduser))->row();
        print_r($row );
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

Ask me if anything goes wrong

Comment: Thanks but can you tell more about it how does it work

Comment: First try it and will explain you later i know this can be modified , but for starters we can try this

Comment: but what about return query i was returning query back to controller

Comment: how can i use without explode

Comment: Is query working in your database ?? is this full filling your need ??

Comment: How do i know that in your controller what you are doing you haven't show any code here. i am not a god man

Comment: try print_r($results); and please please please first try that query in your database so i can know that query is working or not

Comment: change id to your table's primary key also

Comment: my table primary key is id that you have already written in code

Comment: Okk then have you tried print_r($results) ; ? what is its output ?

Comment: the output is Array ( [0] => Array ( [featured] => 1 [group_concat(`id` order by rand() )] => 409,408 ) [1] => Array ( [featured] => 0 [group_concat(`id` order by rand() )] => 237,96,236,40,114,201,305,179,295,63,395,81,323,181,155,312,256,298,335,354,43,339,332,142,258,275,141,102,206,244,319,233,169,138,182,361,266,245,280,297,257,56,176 ) )

Comment: And it is showing error                                                                                   A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: id

Filename: models/show_model_core.php

Line Number: 414

Comment: then try with $paidusers = $results[0][1];

Comment: i have tried but it is showing error                                                                          A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: models/show_model_core.php

Line Number: 414

Comment: See my answer and try that

Comment: sorry! i didnt understand what to replace

Comment: thanks it works but prints two times means the output is doubled

Comment: Prints 2 rows because you have featured 2 posts as from your given result by table [0] => Array ( [featured] => 1 [group_concat(id order by rand() )] =>**409,408** )

Comment: but why it doubles the output

Comment: MY OUT PUT IS Array ( [0] => Array ( [featured] => 1 [id] => 408,409 ) [1] => Array ( [featured] => 0 [id] => 159,126,181,400,353,219,261,46,255,299,249,348,382,72,65,375,195,245,378 ) ) 1
Array ( [0] => Array ( [featured] => 1 [id] => 408,409 ) [1] => Array ( [featured] => 0 [id] => 159,126,181,400,353,219,261,46,255,299,249,348,382,72,65,375,195,245,378) ) 1

Comment: Create a chat and invite me there or post a link to that chat we will discuss there  :)

Comment: i dont have right to chat sorry! because i am starter

Comment: May be you are printing twice at your end because i see no print_r which can double the output in my code

Comment: post your code somewhere or here and let me check whats the problem..
Please post specific code

Comment: but i was not printing double but now it works when i try your new code it works & printing correctly please wait for some seconds i will checking & after that i will reply

Comment: Yes sure but mark my answer as it satisfies your current needs  :)

Comment: it was printing only 408 & 409 which are featured

Comment: & 408 is printing again & again

Comment: there was one correction in your code i think you was pring $paiduser instead of $unpaiduser after foreach($unpaidusers as $unpaiduser)

Comment: can i show you my screen on www.join.me because the code is long

Comment: thanks thanks thanks very much for solving my problem

Comment: yes sure guide me how to join you on www.join.me will resolve there and welcome

Comment: please open www.join.me and then i will send you a code to join on my screen

Comment: CLICK on join meeting on right corner of home page they will ask code and then fill

Answer (score 3):

```
 Example:
 function randomval()
 {
      $this->db->order_by('id', 'RANDOM');
      $this->db->limit(1);
      $query = $this->db->get('tblname');
      return $query->result_array();

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but how can i want to show only featured customers first and after that rest of customers in one query. i wan to show them randomly

Answer (score 1):

Set featured = 1 for paid and featured = 0 for unpaid customers in database. Then use the query 
`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dbc_posts WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY featured DESC, RAND() LIMIT 1");`

Comment: Does it shows both featured & unfeatured by random but without mixing with each other

Comment: I think so. Try it in your project. Currently I don't have any set up like this so I can't check. Don't use featured = 1 in where clause then it only returns paid customers.

Comment: but i want to return both seprately in one query

Comment: Paid and unpaid both customers are coming from this query. Run this query in your database SQL. If the result is fulfill your requirement then use it in your project.